# Saving state of fragment using DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, instance

I used [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) to make the SliderView.

In the first fragment I have a media player with pause button, play button, and stop button.
When I press the play button, it enables the others, and disable itself. 
After that, I go to the other fragment using the Slider Menu. And when I return to the first fragment where my media player is, the buttons are in the initial state. It calls the onCreateView again.

I need to know how to save the state of that fragment to show it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Fragment docs over at Android's developer site.  In their example they show clearly how to save state [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example).  For ease of use I'll copy here :).

Basically, you have to check for saved state in onActivityCreated and save any desired info in onSaveInstanceState as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    .....

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for your player information.
        mIsPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isPlaying", false);
    }
    ......
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("isPlaying", mIsPlaying);
}
```

Comment: Actually I checked it before, but I don't get it. onActivityCreated is called first, so "isPlaying" is false. When I press the play button, should I call: mIsPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isPlaying", true); ??? and do it every time the buttons change state?

Comment: Not quite.  You're correct in that the value will be false when onActivityCreated is first called.  When you leave the fragment however, onSaveInstanceState will be called and here you'll save any values you need to persist.  Then, when you come back to this fragment, onActivityCreated will be called and the savedInstanceState Bundle will contain any data you stored in onSaveInstanceState.  Make sense?

Comment: Well, that explanation is what I needed!.. At first, I actually thought that the whole fragment was saved when I called onSaveInstance.. So I can use the savedInstanceState.getboolean on my onCreateView of the fragment, right? So every time my fragment is created I can set the state of the buttons. Is that a right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you save any values you need during onSaveInstanceState and then load them in onActivityCreated.  The first time the Fragment is loaded, the values will not be saved (as you haven't left yet).  After you've left and come back however, onSaveInstanceState will have been called and you will have had a chance to save any important information. :)

Comment: One more question. It seems the onSaveInstanceState method is only called when I press the Home button and exit the application, not when I change from fragments. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry for such a late response, but it seems you're right.  I had forgot that little piece of information.  What you should be doing instead is saving state in onPause using SharedPreferences and loading them back similar to how you are now, except instead of using the Bundle, you'll use SharedPreferences.  See the example shown here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Just to add a little more information, the reason onSaveInstanceState isn't getting called is because the normal Activity/Fragment lifecycle only calls it when the Activity is destroy or exited.  onPause, however, is called whenever your Activity/Fragment is no longer in use or in the foreground.  Take a look here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thank you very much my friend!. I'll take a look to the SharedPreferences now. I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: No problem, I hope you get it figured out!